# 3D as 2D plots using Matlab data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am trying to plot 3d data as 2d (please refer to the attached figure[image]).

Is that possible at all in Tex (or Matlab)?(Usually, this is done a s a legend, however, when no colors are allowed, I have to plot it as in the attached picture). If so, please provide any hints.
Thank you in advance

Here is also a sample of the data:

```
X=[0 0 0 0 0
0.00499487214258387 0.0100271322719341  0.0151355841667174  0.0203619904285679  0.0257528910437245
0.00703013931750997 0.0141123715001326  0.0213007419561194  0.0286533748405864  0.0362349750090093
0.00856912164753604 0.0172011015018718  0.0259611298569260  0.0349192664533911  0.0441534216317338
0.00984769541100846 0.0197669024060679  0.0298317587516411  0.0401218833508729  0.0507257254049430
0.0109577332470996  0.0219942405774403  0.0331911596116199  0.0446361019206510  0.0564262963381876
0.0119466084732432  0.0239782392419037  0.0361829739474490  0.0486552739640120  0.0614998638245181
0.0128426154484001  0.0257757149277838  0.0388930053871466  0.0522949117805015  0.0660926587477192
0.0136642899493110  0.0274238903416811  0.0413774721254582  0.0556307081325855  0.0703005193527485
0.0144245776620953  0.0289487637697525  0.0436756433487295  0.0587155421791397  0.0741904098771546
0.0151329564382696  0.0303693701768318  0.0458162730087464  0.0615881383770832  0.0778113778863288
0.0157966212085941  0.0317001603416950  0.0478211921655991  0.0642779014739504  0.0812006730740997
0.0164211931300526  0.0329524247496926  0.0497074590478197  0.0668078104510510  0.0843874098612964
0.0170111676966756  0.0341351933703888  0.0514887177522871  0.0691962474012896  0.0873948821954542
0.0175702105696051  0.0352558296774944  0.0531760952694321  0.0714582050315404  0.0902420919849960
0.0181013600452389  0.0363204372087640  0.0547788154484420  0.0736061131758165  0.0929447953582426
0.0186071698801841  0.0373341463673818  0.0563046321253931  0.0756504218986758  0.0955162408504069
0.0190898126701751  0.0383013220178056  0.0577601426467341  0.0776000236025984  0.0979677038151599
0.0195511563564558  0.0392257171221451  0.0591510199088859  0.0794625654482437  0.100308881996065
0.0199928219502558  0.0401105886622858  0.0604821874442227  0.0812446851052654  0.102548194045946];

Y=[1 1 1 1 1
1.00100502512563 1.00100502512563 1.00100502512563 1.00100502512563 1.00100502512563
1.00201005025126 1.00201005025126 1.00201005025126 1.00201005025126 1.00201005025126
1.00301507537688 1.00301507537688 1.00301507537688 1.00301507537688 1.00301507537688
1.00402010050251 1.00402010050251 1.00402010050251 1.00402010050251 1.00402010050251
1.00502512562814 1.00502512562814 1.00502512562814 1.00502512562814 1.00502512562814
1.00603015075377 1.00603015075377 1.00603015075377 1.00603015075377 1.00603015075377
1.00703517587940 1.00703517587940 1.00703517587940 1.00703517587940 1.00703517587940
1.00804020100503 1.00804020100503 1.00804020100503 1.00804020100503 1.00804020100503
1.00904522613065 1.00904522613065 1.00904522613065 1.00904522613065 1.00904522613065
1.01005025125628 1.01005025125628 1.01005025125628 1.01005025125628 1.01005025125628
1.01105527638191 1.01105527638191 1.01105527638191 1.01105527638191 1.01105527638191
1.01206030150754 1.01206030150754 1.01206030150754 1.01206030150754 1.01206030150754
1.01306532663317 1.01306532663317 1.01306532663317 1.01306532663317 1.01306532663317
1.01407035175879 1.01407035175879 1.01407035175879 1.01407035175879 1.01407035175879
1.01507537688442 1.01507537688442 1.01507537688442 1.01507537688442 1.01507537688442
1.01608040201005 1.01608040201005 1.01608040201005 1.01608040201005 1.01608040201005
1.01708542713568 1.01708542713568 1.01708542713568 1.01708542713568 1.01708542713568
1.01809045226131 .01809045226131  1.01809045226131 1.01809045226131 1.01809045226131
1.01909547738693 1.01909547738693 1.01909547738693 1.01909547738693 1.01909547738693];

Z=[0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000
0.0500000000000000 0.100000000000000 0.150000000000000 0.200000000000000 0.250000000000000];
```

Please notice how Z is constant for each column

Comment: Can you provide 5-10 lines of your data for understanding how it looks like? Feels possible with `pgfplots`

Comment: @percusse , I don't know if this is enough:
X=[0          0          0
  0.0144   0.0742   0.1640
  0.02 0.  1025      0.2243];

Y=[1        1          1
   1.009      1.009     1.009
   1.0191    1.0191     1.0191];

Z=[0.05  0.25   0.5]
Can send you a *.mat file also, but I think it is not possible in here

Comment: You can copy the text from matlab screen and paste it into your question. If you select the numbers and click the `{}` button it will show it as a code block. You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link under the question.

Comment: {X=0 0 0
0,00499487214258387 0,0100271322719341 0,0151355841667174
0,00703013931750997 0,0141123715001326 0,0213007419561194
0,00856912164753604 0,0172011015018718 0,0259611298569260
0,00984769541100846 0,0197669024060679 0,0298317587516411},
{Y=[1 1 1
1,00100502512563 1,00100502512563 1,00100502512563
1,00201005025126 1,00201005025126 1,00201005025126
1,00301507537688 1,00301507537688 1,00301507537688
1,00402010050251 1,00402010050251 1,00402010050251
]},
{Z=[0.5 0.1 0.15]}

Comment: Emphasis on the edit link under your question not the comment box.

Comment: @user2536125: You can create a `contour` plot using `contour(X,Y,Z)` and then export that using `matlab2tikz`.

Comment: @Jake, yes, already thought of that as an alternatif, however, I was curious if this it was feasible using pgf or matlab !

Comment: @user2536125: I'm not sure I understand what you mean: The image you're showing *is* a contour plot.

Comment: @Jake , yes, you are right, however, the contour labels are shown as an axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `contour` plot. First, prepare the data in MATLAB:

```
[reshape(X,[],1), reshape(Y,[],1), reshape(Z,[],1)];
```

Then, you can use the data in TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=2},
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=3},
        ]
        \addplot[
            colormap={onlyblack}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(0)},
            contour prepared,
            contour/contour label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=2},
            contour/label distance={1000pt}, % use big number to get one label per contour
            ] table {
            0   1   0.05
            0.00499487214258387 1.00100502512563    0.05
            0.00703013931750997 1.00201005025126    0.05
            0.00856912164753604 1.00301507537688    0.05
            0.00984769541100846 1.00402010050251    0.05
            0.0109577332470996  1.00502512562814    0.05
            0.0119466084732432  1.00603015075377    0.05
            0.0128426154484001  1.00703517587940    0.05
            0.0136642899493110  1.00804020100503    0.05
            0.0144245776620953  1.00904522613065    0.05
            0.0151329564382696  1.01005025125628    0.05
            0.0157966212085941  1.01105527638191    0.05
            0.0164211931300526  1.01206030150754    0.05
            0.0170111676966756  1.01306532663317    0.05
            0.0175702105696051  1.01407035175879    0.05
            0.0181013600452389  1.01507537688442    0.05
            0.0186071698801841  1.01608040201005    0.05
            0.0190898126701751  1.01708542713568    0.05
            0.0195511563564558  1.01809045226131    0.05
            0.0199928219502558  1.01909547738693    0.05
            0   1   0.10
            0.0100271322719341  1.00100502512563    0.10
            0.0141123715001326  1.00201005025126    0.10
            0.0172011015018718  1.00301507537688    0.10
            0.0197669024060679  1.00402010050251    0.10
            0.0219942405774403  1.00502512562814    0.10
            0.0239782392419037  1.00603015075377    0.10
            0.0257757149277838  1.00703517587940    0.10
            0.0274238903416811  1.00804020100503    0.10
            0.0289487637697525  1.00904522613065    0.10
            0.0303693701768318  1.01005025125628    0.10
            0.0317001603416950  1.01105527638191    0.10
            0.0329524247496926  1.01206030150754    0.10
            0.0341351933703888  1.01306532663317    0.10
            0.0352558296774944  1.01407035175879    0.10
            0.0363204372087640  1.01507537688442    0.10
            0.0373341463673818  1.01608040201005    0.10
            0.0383013220178056  1.01708542713568    0.10
            0.0392257171221451  1.01809045226131    0.10
            0.0401105886622858  1.01909547738693    0.10
            0   1   0.15
            0.0151355841667174  1.00100502512563    0.15
            0.0213007419561194  1.00201005025126    0.15
            0.0259611298569260  1.00301507537688    0.15
            0.0298317587516411  1.00402010050251    0.15
            0.0331911596116199  1.00502512562814    0.15
            0.0361829739474490  1.00603015075377    0.15
            0.0388930053871466  1.00703517587940    0.15
            0.0413774721254582  1.00804020100503    0.15
            0.0436756433487295  1.00904522613065    0.15
            0.0458162730087464  1.01005025125628    0.15
            0.0478211921655991  1.01105527638191    0.15
            0.0497074590478197  1.01206030150754    0.15
            0.0514887177522871  1.01306532663317    0.15
            0.0531760952694321  1.01407035175879    0.15
            0.0547788154484420  1.01507537688442    0.15
            0.0563046321253931  1.01608040201005    0.15
            0.0577601426467341  1.01708542713568    0.15
            0.0591510199088859  1.01809045226131    0.15
            0.0604821874442227  1.01909547738693    0.15
            0   1   0.20
            0.0203619904285679  1.00100502512563    0.20
            0.0286533748405864  1.00201005025126    0.20
            0.0349192664533911  1.00301507537688    0.20
            0.0401218833508729  1.00402010050251    0.20
            0.0446361019206510  1.00502512562814    0.20
            0.0486552739640120  1.00603015075377    0.20
            0.0522949117805015  1.00703517587940    0.20
            0.0556307081325855  1.00804020100503    0.20
            0.0587155421791397  1.00904522613065    0.20
            0.0615881383770832  1.01005025125628    0.20
            0.0642779014739504  1.01105527638191    0.20
            0.0668078104510510  1.01206030150754    0.20
            0.0691962474012896  1.01306532663317    0.20
            0.0714582050315404  1.01407035175879    0.20
            0.0736061131758165  1.01507537688442    0.20
            0.0756504218986758  1.01608040201005    0.20
            0.0776000236025984  1.01708542713568    0.20
            0.0794625654482437  1.01809045226131    0.20
            0.0812446851052654  1.01909547738693    0.20
            0   1   0.25
            0.0257528910437245  1.00100502512563    0.25
            0.0362349750090093  1.00201005025126    0.25
            0.0441534216317338  1.00301507537688    0.25
            0.0507257254049430  1.00402010050251    0.25
            0.0564262963381876  1.00502512562814    0.25
            0.0614998638245181  1.00603015075377    0.25
            0.0660926587477192  1.00703517587940    0.25
            0.0703005193527485  1.00804020100503    0.25
            0.0741904098771546  1.00904522613065    0.25
            0.0778113778863288  1.01005025125628    0.25
            0.0812006730740997  1.01105527638191    0.25
            0.0843874098612964  1.01206030150754    0.25
            0.0873948821954542  1.01306532663317    0.25
            0.0902420919849960  1.01407035175879    0.25
            0.0929447953582426  1.01507537688442    0.25
            0.0955162408504069  1.01608040201005    0.25
            0.0979677038151599  1.01708542713568    0.25
            0.100308881996065   1.01809045226131    0.25
            0.102548194045946   1.01909547738693    0.25
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: result]

Note: I have assumed a typo and changed one of your points from `.01809045226131` to `1.01809045226131`.

Comment: Very nice! For getting black lines and labels, you can use `contour/draw color=black,
            contour/contour label style={/tikz/every node/.append style={text=black}}`

Comment: @PiotrWydrych ....Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the package [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) provided by Mathworks to export the most recent plot to an arbitrary file name:

```
matlab2tikz('my3d_plot.tikz');
```

Keep in mind that you have to download this function (and keep it in the active folder for evaluation). Furthermore this function produces for each plot a file called `my3d_plot-n.png` where `n` stands for the n'th plot/subplot.

### 3D plot

Use for instance the matlab plot function

```
imagesc(DATA);
colorbar('location','southoutside')
```

where the function has the options to set the color-limits and color-theme. These options are well described also at mathworks's [homepage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html).

### Save file

Save the file `'my3d_plot.tikz'` in the same directory as your processed latex-file because otherwise the paths inside the file `my3d_plot.tikz` refer to the wrong directory.

### Latex file

Something like the following MWE should make it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document}
\input{my3d_plot.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Did this answer your question or was the question about another feature to plot?

Comment: ,,,,Thanks for the answer, however, this is not really what I am looking for. If you look at the attached figure, you will notice it is a 3D plot, however, the third dimension (z) is constant for each line...In matlab, one can use different colors, to specify Z, however, I am not allowed to use colors for my plot, thus, I think the best way to do that is as shown in the attached figure.

Comment: So you might want to use gray color scale with the command `colormap(gray)`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html

Comment: @strpeter: Or use a `contour` plot